# Values from mysql php array not being displayed

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

This is probably very simple and I apologise in advance, if its a silly question.

I working on a web page, and I have a database which I am calling data from that in the most part is working fine, however I need to use a mysql query which isn't just select all or specific fields:

```
$sqlAuthors = ('SELECT authors.Forename, authors.Surname
                         FROM authors
                         LEFT JOIN BookAuthor ON  authors.AuthorID = BookAuthor.AuthorID
                         LEFT JOIN Books ON  BookAuthor.BookID = Books.BookID
                         WHERE Books.BookID="'.$loopnumber.'"');
```

This query I've tested on the database and works fine, the query will in cases have multiple records.

The code I have is:

```
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
        mysql_select_db('library', $conn);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM Books";
        $result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die("Can't run query");
        $loopnumber = 1;                            
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) ==0 ){echo "No Books have been found";}
        else
        {
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) 
            {
                $sqlAuthors = ('SELECT authors.Forename, authors.Surname
                         FROM authors
                         LEFT JOIN BookAuthor ON  authors.AuthorID = BookAuthor.AuthorID
                         LEFT JOIN Books ON  BookAuthor.BookID = Books.BookID
                         WHERE Books.BookID="'.$loopnumber.'"');
                $Authors  = mysql_query($sqlAuthors,$conn);

                echo'<article class="topContent">
                    <header><h2><a href="../ResponsiveCSS/first post">'.$row->BookName.'</a></h2></header>                   
                    <footer><p class="post-info">Written By: '.print_r(mysql_fetch_array($Authors)).' '.$Authors[Forename].'</p></footer>
```

The last line being where I try to output the values.

However if I have $Authors[Forename] it gives me the error:

> ```
> Notice: Use of undefined constant Forename - assumed 'Forename' in I:\xamptest\htdocs\Library\index.php on line 51
> ```

Even though I have:

```
print_r(mysql_fetch_array($Authors))
```

and that works and outputs:

> ```
> Array ( [0] => J.R.R [Forename] => J.R.R [1] => Tolkien [Surname] => Tolkien )
> ```

So it should recognise it, also the array print out appears no where near the line it is meant to be in, not even n the same DIV, but where it should be there is just "1" echoed.

If I try:

```
'.$Authors[1].'
```

Then I get no errors but nothing is printed out.

No idea if it'll help but heres what the section of the site page looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmiwZ.png

Should be printing the Authors name where it says "Written By:" but instead just has "1".

I'm still fairly new to this, but it has me stumped.

All help much appreciated -Tom

Comment: You're using `mysql_fetch_object` in your while loop; so you're fetching the result as an object, not as an array; but `mysql_fetch_array` for your authors - try being consistent

Comment: But you're injecting an arbitrary number `$loopnumber` in your authors SQL query - it's not related to books in any way, so what are you actually trying to do? And as your authors query uses joins, why aren't you joining to your books query?

Comment: Books can have multiple authors, and authors can write multiple books, I have a joining table to get rid of this many to many relationship. Also has stated the query works, fine I even show you that the array outputs the values, so I don't understand what you're saying.  Please be constructive, instead of criticising what is shown to working.

Comment: As for inconsistencies, yes maybe I should use fetch object, but that doesn't solve why what I do have doesn't work. 

Also loopnumber is not arbitrary, as the page outputs all the books from the database, which have IDs starting at 1.... penny dropped yet? Again I even show the output of the entire array with the values, yet you say I have an irrelevant value in my WHERE clause...

Comment: Ah yes, forgive me for being stupid; your database is guaranteed to have only sequential book id numbers, and can never have any gaps; so you can simply create an extra variable to use rather than using the actual book id.... except it would make your life a lot easier if you did do this all with a single join query

Comment: Try `$Authors['Forename']` instead of `$Authors[Forename]`; or be consistent and fetch your row to $Authors first

Comment: For the time being this works, I can just make it fetch the bookID, but this works, it isn't my priority, I want the author query working. Using the loop number was just a fix to get the query working for testing.

Comment: Tried with '' same result as having a number, it doesn't output anything, or any errors :/

Comment: You've missed my point: `$Authors` is a resultset, not a row.... it doesn't have a `Forename`... you need to `fetch` it to an $authorsrow array (or object) first, then echo $authorsrow['Forename'] (or $authorsrow->Forename)

Comment: Well, in the context you're trying to use it in, it's going to treat Forename as a constant, it's missing quotes so it's not going to be a string, it lacks parens or is not a special language keyword so it's not one of those, and it doesn't have a $ in front of it so it isn't a regular variable, so the parser is going to think it's a constant. In your context, as well, $Authors is a result set, not an array. it's not an array til mysql_fetch_array() is called on it

Comment: I made it to a fetch_object and it works, I've got 3 group projects going on right now and I'm jumping back n' fourth between fetch_array and  fetch_object and  just I completely messed up, I did say it'd be a silly quesion.

Comment: The only silly/dumb questions are the unasked ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A great amount of your code needs cleaning up, but we can focus on that after fixing the problem at hand.

```
$Authors  = mysql_query($sqlAuthors,$conn);
```

That returns a result set from the query, no issues there (besides mysql_query() being deprecated, but we can talk about that later :)

Now, let's assume for a moment a book could have multiple authors, as is the case in many reference texts, and since you're already looping over all the books you are returning. Let's just go ahead and put our new result set inside a similar loop to what you've already done:

```
while($author_row = mysql_fetch_array($Authors)){
    echo $author_row['Forename'];
}
```

The code above is totally incomplete, but hopefully it's a starting point for what you need to do.

Just a few items of note: mysql_*() is deprecated, so switch over to using the mysqli API as soon as you can! People will start yelling at you here if you don't ;)

Make sure you're using prepared statements after cleaning up for security. Easy to protect against if you do it right, but sql injections are nasty.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'd gotten it working by switching to fetch_object instead of array, but hadn't yet figured out the loop, I now have:    `<footer><p class="post-info">Written By: ';while ($Authors = mysql_fetch_object($Aresult)){echo $Authors->Forename.' '.$Authors->Surname.', ';}echo'First Release Date: '.$row->PublishDate.'</p></footer>`
I have no idea what the mysql API is, so better look that up! :) Thanks again.

Comment: So glad that worked for you! Just keep things consistent and you can save yourself a lot of trouble :)
With regards to mysqli, it's not horribly different than using the mysql api. Ideally you grab a DBMS agnostic library or framework, but I digress. Here are the docs if you haven't found them: http://us3.php.net/mysqli
You'll find that it's actually rather powerful when it comes to the old mysql api in fact.